# How can I sort my image sizes on both coordinates?

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have a list of String that are in the form of XxX where X are numbers up to 4 digits long(they are image sizes in (pixels)x(pixels)).

For example:

```
["192x192","64x84","96x96","64x64","292x192","32x32","64x12"]
```

Using a function mySort which is just insertion sort that looks only at the number up to x:

```
mysort []  = []
mysort [x] = [x]
mysort (x:xs) = insert (mysort xs)
    where insert [] = [x]
          insert (y:ys) | takeUntilX x <= takeUntilX y = x : y : ys
                        | otherwise = y : insert ys
```

I get this:

```
["192x192","292x192","32x32","64x84","64x64","64x12","96x96"]
```

Which is only partly sorted, all of the sorted "64x**" remaing in they original order but I want them also to be sorted so I get this:

```
["192x192","292x192","32x32","64x12","64x64","64x84","96x96"]
```

What would be a better solution - modifying function mySort or writing a new function that sorts the partially sorted list?
Can you give me the the basic idea how I could do either?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

res = map (intercalate "x") . sort . map (splitOn "x")
```

I'm using Data.List.Split from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split

Comment: :) There's always somebody out there who actually uses Haskell on a day-to-day basis (unlike me). Fair play - +1

Comment: does't work; sorting:["192x192","64x184","96x96","64x64","292x192","32x32","64x12"] gives ["192x192","292x192","32x32","64x12","64x184","64x64","96x96"] 64s are wrong

Comment: @Ostensibly: See below -- I've figured out what you were talking about (wasn't clear to me before).

Comment: also doesn't work, it outputs the same mistake as the upper solution, ..."64x12","64x184","64x64".... instead of ..."64x12","64x64","64x184"

Comment: This is the output I get: ["192x192","292x192","32x32","64x12","64x64","64x84","96x96"]. If that's not what you get, I'm not sure what's going on -- did you recompile?

Comment: I used ["192x192","64x184","96x96","64x64","292x192","32x32","64x12"] as input. I found the problem, will post in a sec.

Comment: @Ostensibly: The problem is that your desired sorting order is underspecified.

Comment: You now seem to want the first half to be sorted in string order, and the second half to be sorted as ints -- is that right?

Comment: Originaly yes, but I'm satisfied with int ordering. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Ostensibly: *groans* at customer's constantly changing requirements ;)

Answer (score 3):

For future needs in mind, you could also:
1. convert your data to tuples e.g. (64, 64)
2. use builtin sort. It does exatly what you want

I would assume that in the future you will use the data as integers, so converting them as early as possible could save you a lot of trouble in the future.

br,
Juha

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Corrected -- I've figured out what you meant.

I'd separate out the concerns -- (1) parse the strings to get the dimensions; (2) sort the dimensions however you see fit; (3) convert the dimensions back to strings. In other words:

```
import List

stringToDim :: String -> (String,String)
stringToDim s = (a,c)
    where    (a,b) = break (== 'x') s
             c = drop 1 b

dimToString :: (String,String) -> String
dimToString (x,y) = x ++ "x" ++ y

dimsort :: [String] -> [String]
dimsort = map dimToString . sort . map stringToDim
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the final solution I'm happy with although it isn't what I originaly asked for. Modified copy from max taldykin:

```
res x = map (intercalate "x") $ map myshow $ sort $ map (readAsInt) $ map (splitOn "x") x

readAsInt [x,y] = [read x :: Int, read y ::Int]
myshow    [x,y] = [show x, show y]

input:  ["192x192","64x184","96x96","64x64","292x192","32x32","64x12"]
output: ["32x32","64x12","64x64","64x184","96x96","192x192","292x192"]
```

Although it does't give ["192x192","292x192","32x32","64x12","64x64","64x184","96x96"] it is still ok for what I had in mind.

Comment: yeah, my fault. It's more concise to change "sort" to "sortBy (comparing readAsInt)". "comparing" is from Data.Ord

Comment: ... and "readAsInt [x,y] = (read x :: Int, read y :: Int)" with tuple as a result